# Unable to load OTAClient.dll in blue prism

Tags: blueprism, hp-alm

I am trying to connect an HP ALM application using code stage in blue prism. However, the below respective dlls are not loaded properly and throwing error

Description: Compiler error at top section line -8: Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\OTAClient.dll': An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Can you please help me to understand the reason

Comment: Are you only referencing the OTAClient library in the code stage, or as an External Reference in the Code Options tab on the Initialise action?

Comment: @AlexP: I am doing both i.e referencing the OTAClient library in code stage as well as trying to add dll as an external reference in the code options tab

Answer (score 2):

So after some digging I found this:

> Newer OTA clients are NOT compatible with older versions of the
>   product.
>   You MUST use the same version of the OTA client that is being
>   used/provided by your server for the version of the product being
>   accessed.

So this is to say: You need to make sure the OTAClient.dll your object is referencing is the same API version as you HP ALM application.